# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\kadjo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-p_nzw4hf\turtle\

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

I try to install turttle package and i got this arror:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install turtle
Collecting turtle
Using cached turtle-0.0.2.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\kadjo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-p_nzw4hf\turtle\setup.py", line 40
    except ValueError, ve:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

[turtle](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/turtle) is old (last updated at 2009); it certainly Python2-only.

SyntaxError for `except ValueError, ve:` means that you're trying to install it with Python3. To use turtle you most certainly need Python 2.7.